# Websphere 9 conexion a netezza

Tags: java, websphere

Tengo una EAR en java y tiene varias conexiones a websphere entre ellas esta una a netezza al momento de querer trabajar el datasource por medio del código lanza este error

> java.sql.SQLException: null DSRA0010E: Estado SQL = HY000, Código de error = 1,100

antes en was 8.5 si funcionaba actualmente en el 9 no consigo hacerlo trabajar les dejo mi código de conexión del datasource

```
public static Connection getConnection(String saJNDI)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("entra en getConnection");
        DataSource objlDataSource = null;
        Connection objlConn = null; // connection to return
        InitialContext objlContext = null;
        if (!(saJNDI == null)) {
            objlDataSource = (DataSource) datasources.get(saJNDI);
            if ((objlDataSource == null)) {
                objlContext = new InitialContext();
                objlDataSource = (DataSource) objlContext.lookup(saJNDI);
                datasources.put(saJNDI, objlDataSource);
                System.out.println("obtiene el jdni " + objlDataSource);
            }
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("entra en el try para obtener la conexion");
            objlConn = objlDataSource.getConnection();
            // FWLog.info("got connection");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("este es el error " + e);
            // FWLog.error("error getting connection");
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
        return objlConn;
    }
```

Comment: Buenas, en el error que has comentado supongo que lanzara mas que una linea. En tal caso podrías mostrar lo demás ya que podría indicar mejor donde se encuentra el problema.

Comment: Actualización, se agrego un jar nuevo el 3.0 en los JNDI del servidor de was y se soluciono el problema